# Building React Native app on iOS device

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm curious why I need to open Xcode and click "Build and Run" (per https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html#content) in order to be able run my application on my iPhone.

```
$ react-native help
Usage: react-native <command>

Commands:
  - start: starts the webserver
  - bundle: builds the javascript bundle for offline use
  - unbundle: builds javascript as "unbundle" for offline use
  - new-library: generates a native library bridge
  - link: Adds a third-party library to your project. Example: react-native   link awesome-camera
  - android: generates an Android project for your app
  - run-android: builds your app and starts it on a connected Android emulator or device
  - run-ios: builds your app and starts it on iOS simulator
  - upgrade: upgrade your app's template files to the latest version; run this after updating the react-native version in your package.json and running npm install
```

The help page for the `react-native` command shows `run-ios` just to iOS simulator, whereas `run-android` can build to a device or an emulator.

Does anyone know how I can use `react-native-cli`, or other command line tools to be able to build my apps directly to a development environment on my iPhone as if I followed the above docs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is linked to Provisioning Profiles. You need to have a provisioning profile in order to run your app on your device and xCode handles them.

As you don't need them to run on the simulator, you can launch your app directly with react-native-cli. But to run it on your iPhone you'll need to launch xCode to verify with Apple your provisioning profiles.